# Issue with a program in C to check if a number is divisible by 100

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C to check if the entered number is divisible by 100, but I've run into a problem. If I enter a number with 11 digits or more (with the last two digits being zeroes, of course), it says the number is not divisible by 100, even though it is. Help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    long int a;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d" , &a);
    if(a%100==0)
    {printf("This number is divisible by 100");}
    else
    {printf("This number is not divisible by 100");}
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Use `"%ld"` for `long`. (or use `%lld` and `long long`)

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Add this: `printf("%d\n", a);` right after your `scanf` line and try with 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc. You'll see what happens, and when you read up on integer overflow, also why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your number just doesn't fit into `long int` type, so the actual number you get is not what you expect. Try using `unsigned long long`, but be aware that numbers greater than `2^64 - 1` won't fit anyway. Also, you should use `scanf("%llu", &a)` in this case

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it was an issue with the integer type.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many reasons why `scanf` should never be used is that numeric overflow provokes undefined behavior.  Your C library seems to produce a garbage value on overflow.

If you write the program using `getline` and `strtol`, then you can safely check for overflow and print a proper error message:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char *linebuf    = 0;
    size_t linebufsz = 0;
    ssize_t len;
    char *endp;
    long int val;

    for (;;) {
        fputs("Enter a number (blank line to quit): ", stdout);
        len = getline(&linebuf, &linebufsz, stdin);
        if (len < 0) {
            perror("getline");
            return 1;
        }
        if (len < 2)
            return 0; /* empty line or EOF */

        /* chomp */
        if (linebuf[len-1]) == '\n')
            linebuf[len--] = '\0';

        /* convert and check for overflow */
        errno = 0;
        val = strtol(linebuf, &endp, 10);
        if ((ssize_t)(endp - linebuf) != len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Syntactically invalid number: %s\n", linebuf);
            continue;
        }
        if (errno) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", strerror(errno), linebuf);
            continue;
        }

        if (val % 100 == 0)
            printf("%ld is divisible by 100\n", val);
        else
            printf("%ld is not divisible by 100\n", val);
    }
}
```

I tested this on a machine where `long` is 64 bits wide, so it can do most but not all 19-digit numbers:

```
Enter a number (blank line to quit): 1234567890123456789
1234567890123456789 is not divisible by 100
Enter a number (blank line to quit): 12345678901234567890
Numerical result out of range: 12345678901234567890

Enter a number (blank line to quit): 9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807 is not divisible by 100
Enter a number (blank line to quit): 9223372036854775808
Numerical result out of range: 9223372036854775808
```

I suspect that on your computer `long` is only 32 bits wide, so the limit will instead be 2147483647 for you.